# Custom markers icons not displayed on android

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this code :

```
this.service.getListe(data).forEach((data: any) => {
    const marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync(data);
    marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe((params) => {
        this.click(params);
    });
});
```

Now the `getListe()` looks like :

```
getListe(merchants: any) {
    const Liste: BaseArrayClass<any> = new BaseArrayClass<any>();
    merchants.map(item => {
        Liste.push({
            title: item.name,
            animation: 'DROP',
            position: {
                lat: item.lat,
                lng: item.long
            },
            icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/24/Number-1-icon.png',
            disableAutoPan: true
        });
    });

    return Markers;
}
```

I tried and like this :

```
icon: {
    url: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/24/Number-1-icon.png'
}
```

But the same behaviour, the problem is that on emulator and on real device the icon is not changing. On browser mode I have for markers the correct icon that I indicate in BaseArrayClass, but on emulator I have default icon. Have you an idea about that ?

Comment: Try with a URL with `https`

Comment: The app display some error at console?

Comment: nope...........

Comment: works with https, thx a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find some icon with https protocol.

Google may not allow insecure URLs.